# Can't make UiTableView work

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am working on a project on XCode 6 and Swift. 
I need to add a UITableView to a UIViewController, and then fill the table with content.

So, on my default UIViewController, I added a UITableView and a UITableViewCell (using the storyboard). 
Next, I set the UIViewController as the dataSource and delegate for the table.

Finally, I added this code to my view controller.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1


}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return 3
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello world"

    table.reloadData()

    return cell


}
```

However, as I run the project, I get a crash with the following log

```
2015-04-08 21:06:52.820 tableViewTest[12380:783945] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

I've tried anything, I really don't know how to solve this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello world"

    table.reloadData() --> you don't have to reload,

I guess this causes a recursive call and thus crashes

Comment: I've tried, but actually it crashed anyway. @Vig

Comment: what's your console output

Comment: 2015-04-08 21:06:52.820 tableViewTest[12380:783945] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'  @Vig

Comment: That error is saying that you have a UITableViewController (that's what your code says too), but you're telling us you're using a UIViewController. You seem to be confused as to what you're actually doing.

Comment: class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, I don't think you need UITableViewController in your protocol, try removing them and I assume your tableview outlet has delegate and datasource connected to this viewcontroller

Comment: UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDataSource seem to need UITableViewController to work. @Vig

Comment: I need to control the UITableView inside the UIViewController. Are there others ways to do this? I actually need a page like the Instagram profile page. @rdelmar

Comment: You don't need the UITableViewController, you need UIViewController. So it should be ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

Comment: Great consider up voting or approving the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tableview as `IBOutlet` and you need your `ViewController` to be a subclass of `UIViewController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be "conform" to UIViewController; UIViewController is not a protocol. It should read "you need  ViewController's  superclass to be UIViewController".

Comment: Ah yes, how did I miss that

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you're using an `UIViewController` in the storyboard but referencing an `UITableViewController` in the code. Try changing

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

to

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

and put `table.reloadData()` in the `viewDidLoad` function.